# What is the relationship between positional and non-positional consciousness for Sartre?

Tags: existentialism, continental-philosophy, sartre

I am wondering when one is non-positionally conscious of a feeling, is that feeling facticity or also positional consciousness of an object? In a word is reflection in the presence to self duality intentional?

Comment: If I understand the question I think it is answered [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-consciousness-phenomenological/)? "To be self-aware is not to capture a pure self or self-object that exists separately from the stream of experience, rather it is to be conscious of one’s experience in its intrinsic first-person mode of givenness."

Comment: Consciousness is positional and nonpositional at once. A positional (intentional) consciousness of an object is at the same time nonpositional self-consciuosness. The latter is the projection towards one's own possibilities of the object. Those, while "about the object", actually characterize me (self) as what is not this object. Thus, the man is a deficiency in the object.